# Unable to add new users in Google Ad Manager (ex:DFP)

Tags: google-dfp, google-ad-manager

All, I'm unable to add a new user under the Admin > Access & Authorization tab in Google Ad Manager (ex: DFP). (Role > Partner Portal user).

I have this error: Unable to save. Check highlighted errors and try again. Problem is that nothing is highlighted, so I don't know what's wrong.

I'm inviting a third party which has a gmail address, I've also cleared my cache, login/logout. I'm using Chrome, and even tried via my mobile phone (Android/Chrome).

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Maybe the question is better suited at https://superuser.com/ or https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks will try both.

Comment: do you have the right to do so ? Are you admin ?

Comment: Yes I'm the administrator.

Comment: you might need to have a Google Ad Exchange account enable to do so. Do you have one ?

Comment: In the end, I created a specific role and it did work. Looks like there are some restrictions on the role that can be assigned to a user. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are admin then Ad Manager should allow you to add users.Please navigate to Admin > Access & Authority > Users. You may refer to the screenshot attached below.

Now your main problem is that it's not highlighting what's the error. Google Ad Manager is very strict when it comes to permission to access the platform. When you give a general email address such as "example@gmail.com" it won't allow you to add the user. It has to be a registered company email address such as "seb@company.com". In addition, that company should be registered with Google Ad Manager to use their services.

[image: Google Ad Manager Screenshot]